# Making certain content available to members of subspaces

Tags: distributions

maybe it should be pretty obvious, but I don't seem to be able to find a workaround.

I have a Space 'parent' and 2 Spaces 'child1' and 'child2'.
There are users that are members of 'parent' and then users members of 'child1' and 'child2'.
The parent space is set with inheritance towards the children.

I also have a content type 'acme'. I have a view that lists nodes of type 'acme' (current space and parent spaces). The view is placed (panelizer) in both spaces, 'child1' and 'child2',

When a user member of 'parent' visits one of the 'child' spaces, the view shows the 'acme' nodes created either in the parent of in the child space.

But when the user visiting the child is a member of the child, the view only displays the 'acme' nodes that where created (og_group_ref) in the child; but not the 'acme' nodes created (og_group_ref) in the parent.

What I need is the users members of 'child1' and 'child2' to be able to see all the 'acme' nodes created in 'child1' or 'child2', but also the ones created in the parent space.

Is there any obvious solution for that?

TIA!

Comment: FWIW, I've finally solved it by means of adding an extra OG field to the content type: 'group content visibility' and setting it to default to 'public'. This way the views can retrieve all the 'acmes' along the space hierarchy. Not exactly what I wanted because a user member of 'child1' can have access to content of 'child2' (if they can figure out the url). But that will have to do.

Comment: Yet another (interesting) puzzle ... A few things in it I don't understand for sure ... "Space" are ike specific "organic groups", right? What exactly do you mean with that "inheritance" (some OG feature I'm not aware of yet, or something else?)? Those "child1" and "child2": I think some of them should say "exclusive or", no? Consider editing your questions a bit to clarify those things ...